# How to run a program from VSCode in Windows CMD terminal?

Tags: c++, cmd, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I want to be able to run programs from VSCode directly into External terminal (**Windows CMD**) and not in integrated terminal of VSCode. i.e. to show output and take inputs from Windows CMD. How do I do that?

If there is a way to preferably do the same using ***Code Runner extension***, then please let me know that as well.

Comment: set the use external terminal option in the launch options?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I'm sorry can you please elaborate. I did not understand clearly. Where do i find that option? Also will that option be for one project or for all future projects?

Comment: Press `Ctrl + ,`, search for "external terminal" and choose "external" from the drop-down menu of the first result. There are two tabs at the top: "User" and "Workspace". User ist for all projects, workspace overrides the user settings for the current workspace (it is then stored in .vscode/settings.json).